# Intersection of two lines in complex numbers given four points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

> How to find the point of intersection of two lines, given four points, two of which are on each line, in complex numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: Write the equation of the two lines and then solve them to get the desired point.

Comment: How do you write the equation of a line through two points in complex numbers?

Answer (score 10):

Assume $z_1\not=z_2$ and $z_3\not=z_4$.

The condition that $z$ is on the line which passes through two points $z_1,z_2$ is
$$\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}=\overline{\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right)},$$
i.e.
$$(z-z_1)(\overline{z_2}-\overline{z_1})=(z_2-z_1)(\overline{z}-\overline{z_1}),$$
i.e.
$$(\overline{z_2}-\overline{z_1})z-(z_2-z_1)\overline{z}=\overline{z_2}z_1-z_2\overline{z_1}\tag1$$
Similarly, the condition that $z$ is on the line which passes through two points $z_3,z_4$ is
$$(\overline{z_4}-\overline{z_3})z-(z_4-z_3)\overline{z}=\overline{z_4}z_3-z_4\overline{z_3}\tag2$$

Multiplying the both sides of $(1)$ by $(z_4-z_3)$ gives
$$(z_4-z_3)(\overline{z_2}-\overline{z_1})z-(z_4-z_3)(z_2-z_1)\overline{z}=(\overline{z_2}z_1-z_2\overline{z_1})(z_4-z_3)\tag3$$
Multiplying the both sides of $(2)$ by $(z_2-z_1)$ gives
$$(z_2-z_1)(\overline{z_4}-\overline{z_3})z-(z_4-z_3)(z_2-z_1)\overline{z}=(\overline{z_4}z_3-z_4\overline{z_3})(z_2-z_1)\tag4$$

Now $(3)-(4)$ gives
$$(z_4-z_3)(\overline{z_2}-\overline{z_1})z-(z_2-z_1)(\overline{z_4}-\overline{z_3})z$$$$=(\overline{z_2}z_1-z_2\overline{z_1})(z_4-z_3)-(\overline{z_4}-z_3-z_4\overline{z_3})(z_2-z_1),$$
i.e.
$$z=\frac{(\overline{z_2}z_1-z_2\overline{z_1})(z_4-z_3)-(\overline{z_4}z_3-z_4\overline{z_3})(z_2-z_1)}{(\overline{z_2}-\overline{z_1})(z_4-z_3)-(\overline{z_4}-\overline{z_3})(z_2-z_1)},$$
or
$$z=\frac{\Im(\overline{z_2}z_1)(z_4-z_3)-\Im(\overline{z_4}z_3)(z_2-z_1)}{\Im(\overline{z_2-z_1}(z_4-z_3))}.$$
Note that if $\Im(\overline{z_2-z_1}(z_4-z_3))=0$, then the line through $z_1,z_2$ is parallel to the line through $z_3,z_4$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very helpful! Note that the result can be simplified: the terms \bar z1 z1 cancel, idem for z3, and you can write the first and third parenthesis and the denominator as imaginary part: z=( Im(\bar z2 z1) u - Im(\bar z4 z3) v)/Im(v \bar u), where u =z2-z1 and v = z4-z3. I checked that it works!

Comment: @Max A small correction, it seems like your denominator should be Im(\bar v u) instead of Im(v \bar u)

Comment: Oh, your're right, there's a "bug". But I think the denominator is OK, viz. [directly from last line of @mathlove's answer]  (v \bar u - cc) = 2i Im (v\bar u). However, similarly, the numerator should be: (2i Im(\bar z2 z1) v - 2i Im(\bar z4 z3) u), so I think it's here where I switched by error u and v. [Upon cancelling all "2i", of course.]